# Bootstrap row causes FullPageJS to have wrong width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following snippet directly inside the `body` tag:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="section profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                A
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section technical">

    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS file if it is neccessary:

```
body {
    background-color: #808080;
}

.section {
}

    .section.profile {
        background-color: #2980b9;
    }

    .section.technical {
        background-color: #bdc3c7
    }
```

However, when I use FullPageJS, the result is like this:
[image]
(note: their are thin lines at the left and right)

The problem only happens if I use row div. It also happen if I wrap the row by another div. Also, the problem disappear if I resize the browser window.

This is how I call the script, just like the documentation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#container").fullpage();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure what are you expecting to happen, but check this:

- Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or
  `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
  immediate children of rows.

The `container` must be a class, not an id, but this also will add some padding to the sides.

Also, you should move the `.row` class to the upper level id and delete the current one with the `.row` class in it, the row `<div>` can have both classes without any problem.

Comment: Beautiful! I missed the `container` thing. I wrapped my row inside a `.container-fluid` div and it is working now! Thank you!